# immutable flow fails . live test on travis

Tags: immutable.js, flowtype

Hello this questions is having a minimal working example of what Im trying to build.

Im having troubles to run flow-type checker on just simple JS file. Here is how the file looks like

```
// @flow
import type { Map } from 'immutable';
```

And I even build a minimal working (NOT working) example with travis running it.

Here is the repository. It's very simple and only has `flow` and `immutable-js` dependencies.

https://github.com/RusAlex/immutable-flow

and here is the failed Travis-ci build

https://travis-ci.org/RusAlex/immutable-flow/builds/243260858

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flow reads the package.json to find out about imports, but since you moved your `.flowconfig` inside your `src/` folder, it no longer can. If you include the `package.json` by adding `../package.json` to your `[include]`  you get an interesting error:

```
src/flow.js:2
  2: import { Map } from 'immutable';
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^ This modules resolves to "<<PROJECT_ROOT>>/../node_modules/immutable/package.json", which is outside both your root directory and all of the entries in the [include] section of your .flowconfig. You should either add this directory to the [include] section of your .flowconfig, move your .flowconfig file higher in the project directory tree, or move this package under your Flow root directory.
```

Finally, adding `../node_modules/immutable/` will help `flow` resolve everything again.

Alternatively, you could just add `.flowconfig` to the actual project root. It makes things simpler and seems to be the intended default.

Comment: thank you for your asnwer. it's exact what was needed. But I do think it must   not depend on where `.flowconfig` file placed.